# How to import HTML-Elements into Typescript to call a function

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to use a carousel and change the displayed slide inside a typescript-function. Therefore i tried to import the carousel with

```
@ViewChildren('myCarousel') carousel: any;
```

First I just adjusted the activeId of the carousel, but this didn't affect the displayed slider.

```
this.carousel._results[0].activeId = '1';
```

So i tried to use the select()-Function.

```
this.carousel.select('1');
```

But then the error "this.carousel.select is not a function" occured.

The function is working well in html

```
<button (click)="myCarousel.select('1')">change</button> //works
<button (click)="changeTo()">change indirect</button> //error
```

The changeTo-Function looks like this:

```
changeTo() {
    this.carousel.select('1');
}
```

I hope someone knows how to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change to **`@ViewChild('myCarousel') carousel: ElementRef;`**

Comment: Try changing `@ViewChildren('myCarousel') carousel: any;` to `@ViewChild('myCarousel') carousel: ElementRef;
`

and then check what are you getting inside `ngAfterViewInit` when you log `carousel`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That fixed it!